# Prove divergence of sum $\ln(1+1/n)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, functions, convergence-divergence

> We have seen the harmonic series is a divergent series whose terms approach $0$. Show that $$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \text{ln}\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)$$ is another series with this property.

Denote $a_n = \text{ln}\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right).$ Then, $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\text{ln}\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right) = \text{ln}\left(1 + \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\right) = 0,$$ since $\text{ln}(x)$ is a continues function on its domain. However, I can't seem to prove that the series is divergent. I know the proof for the harmonic series (which is quite clever in my opinion), and I wondered whether this question required a similar approach?

Comment: Can you show that $\sum \bigl(\frac{1}{n} - a_n\bigr)$ is (absolutely) convergent?

Comment: That series is a telescoping sum: $$\ln (1+ \frac{1}{n}) = \ln (n+1) - \ln n$$

Comment: Another way to do it would be to use the inequality $\frac{x}{x+1} < \log \left( 1 + x \right)$ for $x>-1$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Hint**:

$$\ln\frac21+\ln\frac32+\ln\frac43+\cdots\ln\frac{n+1}n=\ln\frac{2\cdot3\cdot4\cdot\cdots(n+1)}{1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot\cdots n}.$$

Comment: Haha, beautifully done.

Answer (score 4):

For all $n\in\mathbb{N}^\star$ :

$$\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)=\ln\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)=\ln(n+1)-\ln(n)$$

so that :

$$\sum_{n=1}^N\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)=\ln(N+1)-\ln(1)=\ln(N+1)\underset{N\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}+\infty$$

and the divergence of the series $\sum_{n\ge1}\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)$ is proved.

Note that this gives us a proof (one of the easiest ones) of the divergence of the harmonic series, since :

$$\forall n\in\mathbb{N}^\star,\,\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\le\frac{1}{n}$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

This is a series with positive terms, and $\;\ln\Bigl(1+\dfrac1n\Bigr)\sim_\infty\dfrac1n$.